# Callback with int argument from Native Android on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, future, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to receive a callback from Android Native on my Flutter app. Nevertheless, it seems to be working. So far, my implementation looks like the following:

**Invoking method from Android side**

Firstly I have implemented a method call in order to send the values which I require on Dart

```
int length = 1234;

handler.post(() -> {
    if (channel != null) {
        channel.invokeMethod("onDone", length);
    }
});
```

**Receive the callback on dart side**

Secondly, I have implemented a platform handler in order to receive those calls. Nevertheless, I believe that the map is failing (but I am not receiving any error message)

```
// Receive callbacks from native platform
Future platformCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
  switch (call.method) {
    // Case called when synthesization of an audio cue has been completed
    case "onDone":

      final args = call.arguments as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      break;
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? I receive the call on `onDone` method but I can not get access to the argument.

I would be expecting to get my int as an argument

Comment: Write `final args = call.arguments as int;` At the Java end you are passing in a primitive, not a map - so that's what you'll get out at the Dart end.

Comment: Indeed, that s exactly the answer. Thanks!